# Declaration warning when extending _afterLoad() in AbstractModel

Tags: model, store-view, extend

I've created a backend module to which I've added the possibility to set storeview specific data today. That worked and showed up fine. So I'm trying to load and save my storeview data now but it just won't work. I took the code from [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/191844) and I'm using Magento 2.3.3.

Here is my Model code in which I'm trying to load and save the storeview settings:

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Module extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Define resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module');
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object
     * @return void
     */
    protected function saveStore($object)
    {
        $condition = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('item_id = ?', $object->getId());
        $this->getConnection()->delete($this->getTable('company_module_store'), $condition);
        foreach ((array)$object->getData('store_id') as $store) {
            $storeArray = [
                'item_id' => $object->getId(),
                'store_id' => $store,
            ];
            $this->getConnection()->insert(
                $this->getTable('company_module_store'),
                $storeArray
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _afterSave(AbstractModel $object)
    {
        if (!$object->getIsMassStatus()) {
            $this->saveStore($object);
        }

        return parent::_afterSave($object);
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
     */
    public function loadStore(AbstractModel $object)
    {
        $select = $this->getConnection()->select()
            ->from($this->getTable('company_module_store'))
            ->where('item_id = ?', $object->getId());

        if ($data = $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select)) {
            $array = [];
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $array[] = $row['store_id'];
            }
            $object->setData('store_id', $array);
        }

        return $object;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _afterLoad(AbstractModel $object)
    {
        if (!$object->getIsMassDelete()) {
            $this->loadStore($object);
        }

        return parent::_afterLoad($object);
    }
}
```

When I load this in backend I get:

> Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Declaration of Company\Module\Model\Module::_afterLoad(Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object) should be compatible with Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::_afterLoad()

I guess the problem is that _afterload originally doesn't accept any arguments? But then how can I solve my problem? Really at a loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes1:**

Check `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::_afterLoad()` and as this method signature`_afterLoad()` does not have any argument,So

```
return parent::_afterLoad($object);
```

**Should be**

`return parent::_afterLoad();`

**Changes2:**

Also, You need to `protected function _afterLoad(AbstractModel $object)` 
to `protected function _afterLoad()`

**Changes3:**

**and**
`if (!$object->getIsMassDelete()) {`

**to**

```
$object = $this;
if (!$object->getIsMassDelete()) {
```

Comment: If I remove $object from the return I still get `Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Declaration of Company\Module\Model\Module::_afterLoad(Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object) should be compatible with Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::_afterLoad()` because it is used as an input argument. Is there a way to get the object without passing an argument?

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot. :)